# javascript fades out but does not fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

i have the following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script  type="text/javascript">
        function goToSignup() {
            $("#register").fadeIn("fast");
            $("#login").fadeOut("fast");
        }
        function goToLogin() {
            $("#login").fadeIn("fast");
            $("#register").fadeOut("fast");
        }                        
    </script>
```

that's my asp code:

```
   <div id="login" class="animate form">

       <h1>Log in</h1> 
      <p> 
          <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your username </label>
          <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="username"  name="username" type="text" placeholder="myusername"/>
     </p>
     <p> 
     <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
     <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="password"  name="password" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" /> 
     </p>
     <p class="keeplogin"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" /> 
<label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
   </p>

   </div>

   <div id="register" class="animate form" >
    <h1> Sign up </h1> 
     <p> 
       <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Firstname</label>
      <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname"  style="color: red;">*</label>
         <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"
        ValidationGroup="registerGRP" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" onservervalidate="cusCustom_RegisterValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
      <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="Firstname" name="usernamesignup" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" />
        </p>
      <p> 
     <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Lastname</label>
     <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname"  style="color: red;">*</label>
      <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="Lastname" name="usernamesignup" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690" />
      </p>
       <p> 
       </div>
```

that's my vb.net code:

```
    Protected Sub btn_login_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_login.Click
    If Session("valid") Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.[GetType](), "foo", "goToLogin()", True)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub btn_signup_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_signup.Click
    'Dim tbUserName As TextBox = Page.FindControl("username")
    'tbUserName.required = False
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.[GetType](), "foo", "goToSignup()", True)
End Sub
```

when i click on the button the div fades out but the other div does not fade in when i inspect my page i get the container but it's invisible in the page

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you realize you are calling `goToSignup()` in both cases?

Comment: What happens when you manually enter `$("#register").fadeIn("fast");` or `$("#login").fadeOut("fast");` into your browser console on the page?

Comment: @epascarello yeah i know that and it has nothing to do with what's happening to me ..

Comment: @MicahDelaneBolen nothing happens..

Comment: If @epascarello's comment has nothing to do with your error, then please explain exactly how you reproduce it.

Comment: I don't see closing div tags.  Can you paste the rendered html somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if in your css you've set

```
visibility:hidden;
```

for one of your panels.
Becouse fadein work on

```
display:none;
```

here there's a workaround:

```
   function goToSignup() {
        $('#register').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn('fast');            
        $("#login").fadeOut("fast");
    }
    function goToLogin() {
        $('#login').css('visibility','visible').hide().fadeIn('fast');            
        $("#register").fadeOut("fast");
    }
```

Comment: it does not work.. do you have another way to show a div a hide another one in javascript?

Comment: all seems to work properly check a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/sgnPc/1/
If your code don't work use JSFiddle and post there your output code (HTML+CSS+JS) so I can take a look...